# Any suggestions for a textbook to self-study Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

I'm currently in secondary school and I am looking to self-study some introductory real analysis, I have studied the prerequisites on MIT OCW but they have no real analysis stuff so I was hoping someone could suggest a textbook for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To help people make a good recommendation for you it would be good to let us know what level of math you've already mastered. Is it just the standard Calculus course through multivariable calculus? Have you done any course that introduces you to the ideas of logic and proofs?

Comment: On the same web page, you could find their real analysis course and related archived syllabus, problem sets, lecture notes, etc.. Their textbooks were indicated in those syllabi.

Comment: Rudin is a great book for students at a certain stage of development, but it's probably too hard for a secondary school student.  Spivak's Calculus, although arguably not an analysis textbook, is a great stepping-stone to something like Rudin, and the most user-friendly intro to epsilon-delta arguments out there.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer Robert G.Bartle. You can go through the book in the form of PDF which is available on the Internet. Its quite comprehensive and concise. Just give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer*: I think this is a beautiful thing to do, especially if you aren't yet at the university.

First of all I think that you should revise what is usually meant by *set theory* (and "mathematical logic"); no axiomatic for the moment, but enough stuff to start having a feel for what does it mean to do proofs (a *working knowledge* of sets is a must for whatever mathematics you will meet from now on): this will help when you'll get stuck facing proofs that use such tricks, De Morgan's laws, ecc...

Even if it is not a Real Analysis textbook, I like Munkres, *Topology*: I think the first chapter will do its job, with respect to sets and logic. Note that usually - at least here in Italy -  Real Analysis textbooks have, in the first chapters, an introduction to all this stuff (*Baby Rudin* excluded).

That being said, I think *Baby Rudin* is the best place to start if you want to explore the world of (elementary) analysis (but please also look at other people's question/answers: MSE is full of resource recommendation questions): its treatment of the subject is "topological", in a sense which will be more clear to you later, starting from the definition of metric space and developing the theory of continuous functions *inside* metric spaces (which, though being more abstract, covers several special cases at once, preventing you from understanding them as separate things); and learning a bit of topology simultaneously with analysis puts in your hands a number of useful tools also for other branches of mathematics. (Be anyway prepared to be discouraged by very terse proofs, which going through (by yourself as much as you can, and asking for help only when you have a solution to check) is essential to learn learning the subject.)

Consider also J. Dieudonneé, *Foundations of Modern Analysis*: in the first chapters there is more or less what you need to start doing analysis, and, even being an extremely terse book sometimes, it's a good read to do in parallel with Rudin.

Last, but not less important: do as much exercises as you can, in particular proofs over mechanical busywork.

Comment: Dieudonne would disagree with you. ("It is clear that students must have a good working knowledge of classical analysis before approaching this course.") I wouldn't be surprised if Rudin and Munkres disagreed as well.

Comment: Defining the derivative for the first time in a Banach space isn't the right way to start doing analysis, I totally agree with it, but the first two or three chapters are quite readable by someone starting from zero. I recommended to start with Rudin because PMA is able to deliver a sort of "intuition of the abstract", but there are of course more suitable text for an absolute beginner. Could you please elaborate on why Munkres text' sset-theoretical introduction is not suitable for the OP?

Comment: Munkres himself writes: 'I do not even assume the reader knows much set theory. Having said that, I must hasten to add that unless the reader has studied a bit of analysis or "rigorous calculus," much of the motivation for the concepts introduced in the first part of the book will be missing. Things will go more smoothly if he or she already has had some experience with continuous functions, open and closed sets, metric spaces, and the like, although none of these is actually assumed.' Also although I can't speak for the OP, I know from my own experience the danger of rushing into abstraction.